# iPhone iOS how to add linear gradient to a UIButton under the button's text or image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, gradient

I'm working on creating fancy looking UIbuttons by adding linear gradient to the button. However I'm not sure at which index I need to add the gradient. The code that I have currently places the gradient over the image/text.

**How can I insert a sublayer to a UIButton under the text/image sublayer?** It is important for me to keep the text and the image of a button visible!

```
+(void)addLinearGradientToView:(UIView*)view TopColor:(UIColor*)topColor BottomColor:(UIColor*)bottomColor
{
    for(CALayer* layer in view.layer.sublayers)
    {
        if ([layer isKindOfClass:[CAGradientLayer class]])
        {
            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
        }
    }
    CAGradientLayer* gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1);
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds;
    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[topColor CGColor], (id)[bottomColor CGColor], nil];
    //    [view.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
    if(view.layer.sublayers.count>0)
    {
        [view.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:view.layer.sublayers.count-2];
    }else {
        [view.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have written some sample code to do this sort of thing: https://github.com/kristopherjohnson/gradientbuttons

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Add it to the layer of your custom button:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = customButton.layer.bounds;

gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4f alpha:0.5f].CGColor,
                        nil];

gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                           nil];

gradientLayer.cornerRadius = customButton.layer.cornerRadius;
[customButton.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

where `customButton` is your custom `UIButton`.

Comment: this solution isn't working 100%. The buttons do get a gradient, but it overflows on the bottom corners. See: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mguy6owuayjgxvc/Screen%20Shot%202012-09-03%20at%2017.50.30.png  How can this be fixed?

Comment: @murze Looks like your button or its container view is missing the clipsToBounds = YES property to be set. This will clip the overflow you are experiencing.

Comment: [gradientLayer.masksToBounds = YES];  <-- do that

Comment: Sorry, responding to an old thread - I had the same issue as murze and I had accidentally put my code in the viewDidLoad() method, so the button's bounds had not been correctly set yet.  I moved it to viewDidAppear() and it works correctly.

Answer (score 9):

For what you are trying to achieve, always insert at index 0.

I wrote [an article](http://blog.hawkimedia.com/2011/11/ui-polish-in-an-instant/) about this sort of thing recently that you may find interesting.

Comment: Thanks! My text was missing after I added the gradient layer, but only in iOS 6, iOS 7 still showed the text. After changing to Insert it now works for both.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
@IBOutlet weak var gButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let topGradientColor = UIColor.red
    let bottomGradientColor = UIColor.yellow

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    gradientLayer.frame = gButton.bounds

    gradientLayer.colors = [topGradientColor.cgColor, bottomGradientColor.cgColor]

    //Vertical
    //gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    //gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)

    //Horizontal
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)

    gButton.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to achieve this

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = <#View Variable Name#>.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)([UIColor colorWithRed:0.337 green:0.596 blue:1.000 alpha:1.000].CGColor),(id)([UIColor colorWithRed:0.757 green:0.459 blue:1.000 alpha:1.000].CGColor),(id)([UIColor colorWithRed:0.310 green:0.835 blue:1.000 alpha:1.000].CGColor),nil];
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.0);
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1.0);
[<#View Variable name#>.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

I got this tool that makes it easy to select your colors and automatically output the code for the gradient.  Very handy I use it everyday
    [itunes.apple.com/gb/app/gradient-creator/id1031070259?mt=12](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/gradient-creator/id1031070259?mt=12)