# Create a Button with Background Color for Normal/Pressed and Active State

Tags: ios, uibutton, state

I am new to iOS development and want to create a button which will change the background color based on the following state

1. Normal - #00aa6e
2. Pressed - #009762
3. Active - #009762

Can i do this without using any image? I have 8 types of button in my application and that would lead to increase in asset size for using so many images.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIColor * color1 = (UIColor *)UIColorFromRGB(0xFF00FF)
    ...// set up ur background color here

    [button setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:color1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:color2] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:color3] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button addTarget:self action:selector(btnSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];   
}

 + (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

- (IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender {
    [sender setSelected:YES];
}
```

`setBackgroundImage` will resize ur background image according to ur button's size, u don nid to resize images for button

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you can. An answer you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808888/is-it-even-possible-to-change-a-uibuttons-background-color):

```
UIButton *loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[loginButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHighlight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonNormal:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (void)buttonHighlight:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.backgroundColor = (UIColor *)UIColorFromRGB(0xFF00FF);
}

- (void)buttonNormal:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x00FFFF);
}
```

Apple doesn't support 0xRRGGBB recording method. If you want to use your colors as hex you can use [HexColors library](https://github.com/mRs-/HexColors) or use solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560081/how-can-i-create-a-uicolor-from-a-hex-string) answer:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

All you need now to combine this two solutions.. And one more thing: If you don't want to avoid big images as background color you can use a pattern:

```
UIColor *col = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:<#(UIImage *)#>];
```

or linear gradient:

[iPhone iOS how to add linear gradient to a UIButton under the button's text or image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585103/iphone-ios-how-to-add-linear-gradient-to-a-uibutton-under-the-buttons-text-or-i)

Comment: this changes the Title color. i want to change the background color.

Comment: Okey i modified my answer to work with background. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,50 , 50, 50)];
 [myButton setBackgroundColor: [UIColor greenColor]];
 [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 [self.view addSubview:myButton];
 [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selected:) forControlEvents: (UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
 }

 -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
 -(IBAction)pressed:(id)sender{
  UIButton *myButton = (UIButton*)sender;
 [myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

 }
  -(IBAction)selected:(id)sender{
 UIButton *myButton = (UIButton*)sender;
 [myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 }
```

Here

Green - normal, 
Blue - Pressed,
Red - selected.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

@Wilson L answer worked perfectly.

For those who code using Swift, here is the code:

```
func imageFromColor(color:UIColor) -> UIImage{
    var rect:CGRect  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    var context:CGContextRef  = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor );
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    var image:UIImage  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

    backButton.setBackgroundImage(imageFromColor(UIColor(red: 8/255, green: 75/255.0, blue: 122/255.0, alpha: 1.0)), forState: .Normal)
    backButton.setBackgroundImage(imageFromColor(UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 60/255.0, blue: 93.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)), forState: .Selected)
```